# culture locale make up

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo, culture

The following is the culture locale for Belgium with the french language: fr-BE

fr is the Two Letter ISO Language Name

But what is the correct term/name for the "BE" aspect of the culture local?

Comment: Is it the country code? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx)

Answer (score 1):

In [.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx), it is called “subculture code”.

In most other contexts in localization, the term “locale” is used instead of “culture”. In [BCP 47](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47), *Tags for Identifying Languages,* the “fr” part in “fr-BE” is called “primary language subtag”, and it is by definition a language code (not name) in the ISO 639 family of standards; the “BE” part is a “region subtag”. A region code is in most cases a two-letter code from the ISO 3166-1 standard. Most, but not all, such codes refer to countries.